# Determine if a process has suspended

Tags: c++, c, process, operating-system, signals

I try to send a SIGTSTP signal to a particular process, but how to determine if the process has actually suspended using C library functions or syscalls in Linux?

Comment: Context usually helps.  Why do you want to know?  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I want to do this in a C program

Comment: I believe you're confused in regards to the limitations of C; C doesn't even require multiple processes, which is a prerequisite for your question. Hence, this isn't a C question. If you research in terms of "How do I determine if a process has suspended in [*insert operating system info here*]?", then you might come up with a better answer.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue "How do I determine *programmatically* if a process has suspended in *[insert operating system info here]*?" Otherwise, this may as well be migrated to Superuser.

Answer (score 6):

Read from `/proc/[pid]/stat`.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), you can get the status of a process from this file:

> state %c
>
> One character from the string "RSDZTW" where R is running, S is
>   sleeping in an interruptible wait, D is waiting in uninterruptible
>   disk sleep, Z is zombie, T is traced or stopped (on a signal), and W
>   is paging.

Comment: @anthony-arnold , the user need 15 reputation to cast an up-vote , since i find your answer good , i'll cast it on his behalf.

Comment: Pity this doesn't work on a Mac. But you can always run a `ps` as a subprocess.

Comment: @vy32 True, and this is just one of a few different pays of doing it. Without knowing more about the asker's environment I can't formulate a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still need 4 to go! Great help!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone who as curious as me!

The simple answer is that there is only one STATIC, consistent way to check status, which is from `/proc/[pid]/stat`, BUT if you want to have as few architecture dependencies as possible and don't want to do that, you can check the signal.

Signals can only be seen once, so you'll have to keep track of it yourself, but `waitpid` can tap a process to see if any signals have been received since you last checked:

```
    BOOL is_suspended;
    int status;
    pid_t result = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);

    if(result > 0) { // Signal has been received
        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            is_suspended = true;
        } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
            is_suspended = false;
        }
    }
```